How to transform $\max |x|$ such that $x \in S$ in a problem without the absolute value?
Given an optimization problem $\max |x|$ such that $x \in S$, how can I transform it into an equivalent problem that does not require the absolute value condition?
I know that for a minimization problem
\begin{align*}
\min |x| \text{ s.t. } x \in S
\end{align*}
this can be done by introducing an addtional varibale $t$ and have
\begin{align*}
\min t \text{ s.t. } x \in S, x \leq t, -x \leq t
\end{align*}
but I have issues finding a similar formulation for the maximization problem. I tried to first reformulate it as
\begin{align*}
\min -|x| \text{ s.t. } x \in S
\end{align*}
but got stuck there.

The maximization problem is non-convex. The only way around is a mixed-integer model.

But what about transforming it like mentioned in the answer?

The answer shows how to minimize $|x|$, not maximize it. It is equivalent to what you already wrote in the first part of your question.

Oh true. Could you elaborate on your mixed-integer model please?

Same as here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#exact-absolute-value

You can introduce the auxiliary variable $w$ such that we have $w \geq x$ and $w \geq - x$. Then, your problem is then $\min w$.

thank you very much for the answer. I am not sure I understand correctly. Why do we need $u$ and $v$ when we minimize over $w$? So the problem would be
\begin{align*}
\min w \
w&\geq u\
w&\geq v\
u &\geq x \
v &\geq -x\
x &\in S
\end{align*} ?

@samabu yes, upon reflection I do not think we need those variables. Can simply rephrase in terms of $w$. See me edited answer

Thank you, this makes sense!
